# How Select text on mouseover and then put it into a variable for further use in php

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to do exactly as the web page http://www.metrolyrics.com/lose-yourself-lyrics-eminem.html

When you hover over a paragraph, to it moves the block with a share-button and the paragraph text is put in the variable.

Can somebody help me with this please?

here is what I found, but I can not understand why does not work:

```
$('.line').hover(function(){
$('.line').removeClass('hover');
$(this).addClass('hover').next().addClass('hover').next().addClass('hover').next().addClass('hover');
});


$('.line').hover(function(){
$('.line').removeClass('hover');
$("#share-image").appendTo(this);
.appendTo("#destination");$(this).addClass('hover').next().addClass('hover').next().addClass('hover').next().addClass('hover');
});
```

css:

```
.line.hover {
background-color: #3333FF;
}
```

Comment: it's hard to help without seeing your code. what have you got so far? what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Where is the code, where is the problem, where is the work you done?

Comment: i want a car like this: http://autochunk.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/d.jpg please build it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `mouseover` a group of lyrics get its offset relative to the container and the height then apply that to another div that's absolutely positioned to the right.

This code should get you like 85% there.

Here is my JS:

```
var $share = $('<div class="share">f p t</div>'),
    $lyrics = $('.lyrics');

$lyrics.append($share);

$lyrics.on('mouseover', 'p', function () {

  var $this = $(this),
      height = $this.height(),
      top = $this.position().top;

  $share
    .css({
      top: top,
      height: height,
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    })
    .data(
      'lyrics', 
      $this.text()
    );

});

$share.on('click', function () {
  alert($share.data('lyrics'));
});
```

and here is a little demo: http://jsbin.com/jicekoca/3/edit

Comment: Awesome! You really helped me. looks so pretty) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for, but not sure.

HTML:

```
<p id='paragraph'>This is text</p>

<p id='textInsert'>Text will go here</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#paragraph').on('mouseenter', function() {

    var text = $(this).val();

    $('#textInsert').text( text );

});
```